# In Excel VBA run SQL "SELECT ... INTO ... IN ...." Statement

Tags: sql, vba, excel, dao

I can't seem to find any good reference or example of how to get this to work.  I have a database which is stored on an AS/400 (my local MS Access database [stored on a network drive] has linked tables to the 400, using ODBC/DSN).  My utility works just fine passing SQL statements to through Access to retrieve data from the 400 using the linked tables.  The problem is that with some of the larger reports and the fact that the 400 is several states away, it can take several hours to run the reports.  The settled on solution to this is to create a local "copy" of the tables needed with just the data set that is relevant to the reports, which is a considerably smaller data set.  Obviously this has the down side of not being "live" data but I can live with that.  Ultimately what I want to do is gather the relevant  data from the linked table and save it to separate database that is local to the client so that it could be used if offsite/offline and to increase the speed of the report.

network location stored database = DB1 (Tabled linked to AS/400)
local client stored database = DB2 (relevant data set created by below SQL, non-linked tables named the same as the linked tables)

Below is the SQL statement that I'm trying to get to work using VBA & DAO

```sql
SELECT 
    DB1_TABLEA.FIELD1, 
    DB1_TABLEA.FIELD2, 
    DB1_TABLEA.FIELD3, 
    DB1_TABLEA.FIELD4, 
    DB1_TABLEA.FIELD5, 
    DB1_TABLEA.FIELD6, 
    DB1_TABLEA.FIELD7, 
    DB1_TABLEA.FIELD8 
INTO 
    DB1_TABLEA IN 'Local_DB_Copy.accdb'    <== Creating non-linked copy 
FROM 
    DB1_TABLEA
WHERE 
    (
        ((DB1_TABLEA.FIELD4) Like 99999) 
        AND 
        ((DB1_TABLEA.FIELD6)="02" Or (DB1_TABLEA.FIELD6)="22")
    )
;
```

I already have my program working fine and returning/processing data from the AS/400 DB.  I just need to be able to get the above to work so that people have the option to run a local copy that will process much faster.

Below is the code that I tried, but of course it fails or I wouldn't be here.

```vb
Sub gCreateLocalDBTables()
    Dim DBPath As String
    Dim LocalDBPath As String
    Dim sSQL As String
    Dim DB As DAO.Database
    Dim DB2 As DAO.Database
    Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
        LocalDBPath = "AS400_Local.accdb"
        sSQL = "SELECT DB1_TABLEA.FIELD1, DB1_TABLEA.FIELD2, DB1_TABLEA.FIELD3, DB1_TABLEA.FIELD4, DB1_TABLEA.FIELD5, DB1_TABLEA.FIELD6, DB1_TABLEA.FIELD7, DB1_TABLEA.FIELD8 INTO DB2_TABLEA IN '" & LocalDBPath & "' FROM DB1_TABLEA WHERE (((DB1_TABLEA.FIELD4) Like 99999) AND ((DB1_TABLEA.FIELD6)='02' Or (DB1_TABLEA.FIELD6)='22'));"
        Set DB = OpenDatabase(LocalDBPath, False, False)
        DB.TableDefs.Delete ("DB2_TABLEA")
        DB.Close
        DBPath = Interaction.GetSetting("Cust_Tools", "Settings\Report_Planning", "400DB_Location")
        Set DB2 = OpenDatabase(DBPath, False, False)
        Set RS = DB2.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
        RS.Close
        DB2.Close
        Set RS = Nothing
        Set DB = Nothing
        Set DB2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

I know the SQL works as I have tested it from inside MS Access.  I just can't find info on how to get it to work being passed from Excel VBA

Comment: What error do yuu get?

Comment: @Kubie - on the line `Set RS = DB2.OpenRecordSet (sSQL)`  I get the following error "Run-time error '3067': Query input must contain at least one table or query."

Comment: I have also tried changing the line `Set RS = DB2.OpenRecordset (sSQL)` to `DB2.Execute sSQL` and still receive the same error :/

Comment: Have you considered trying ADODB instead of DAO? We also heavily use mainframe here and ADODB works pretty well for me.

Comment: Your setup is not clear. *I have a database which is stored on the mainframe* ... this mostly means IBM's DB2. How does MS Access fit into this? Do you have linked tables to DB2 inside MS Access.

Comment: What is `DBPath = Interaction.GetSetting()`? How does it relate to *LocalDBPath*?

Comment: @Parfait - I've updated my original question to clarify my setup.  `DBPath = Interaction.GetSetting()` pulls the location of the network database file (the one with the linked tables) from a registry setting.  LocalDBPath is the path of the database which will have the relevant data set created by the `Select .... Into...In` SQL statement.  Those tables will be named the same as the linked tables but will not be linked

Comment: Why are you using the linked table network database file? Just use the local copy per my answer below.

Comment: @Parfait - I want to use the local copy, but the local copy needs to be populated with the relevant data set from the network/linked tables. 
 Additionally, to keep from having to rewrite a ton of code, the table names in the local copy must be the same as the linked tables in the network copy.  The networked copy of the database uses the IBM Client Access ODBC driver to handle the AS/400 login requirements.

Comment: An AS/400 is not a mainframe. This should be tagged with AS400 or I-series whichever exists for i-series/AS?400 topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign an action query like a make-table query (i.e., `SELECT` with `INTO` call) to a recordset. Consider executing your `DROP` and `SELECT ... INTO` action queries prior to opening recordset on the local table. Also, it is unclear why you are opening a second database or what the path points to. Below opens a recordset on the mainframe data:

```vb
Set DB = OpenDatabase(LocalDBPath, False, False)

DB.Execute "DROP TABLE DB2_TABLEA", dbFailOnError
DB.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError

Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM DB2_TABLEA")
```

---

Furthermore, the `IN` clause in your make-table query is unnecessary as you are currently connected to the very database you are running the action on. Simply remove it (<strike>'" & LocalDBPath & "'</strike>). Also, `LIKE` expressions without wildcards and on numbers should be replaced with `=`

```sql
SELECT 
    DB1_TABLEA.FIELD1, 
    DB1_TABLEA.FIELD2, 
    DB1_TABLEA.FIELD3, 
    DB1_TABLEA.FIELD4, 
    DB1_TABLEA.FIELD5, 
    DB1_TABLEA.FIELD6, 
    DB1_TABLEA.FIELD7, 
    DB1_TABLEA.FIELD8 
INTO 
    DB2_TABLEA 
FROM 
    DB1_TABLEA
WHERE 
    (
        ((DB1_TABLEA.FIELD4) = 99999) 
        AND 
        ((DB1_TABLEA.FIELD6)='02' OR (DB1_TABLEA.FIELD6)='22')
    )
;
```

In fact, consider saving the query inside the MS Access database  (Ribbon -> Create -> Query Design -> SQL View) and call it as a named object and avoid any long SQL in VBA.

```vb
DB.Execute "DROP TABLE DB2_TABLEA", dbFailOnError
DB.Execute "mySavedQuery", dbFailOnError

Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM DB2_TABLEA")
```

Comment: So local copy of database does not exist prior to running this code?

Comment: if the local copy exists, the tables in it will be deleted and recreated to refresh the data.

Comment: Parfait - I've marked this as the answer.  I realized that `& DBPath &` in my SQL statement should have been `& LocalDBPath &`.  Once I made that change, then my SQL functioned perfectly using the `db.Execute` method that you suggested

Comment: Great to hear! Glad to help. I use DB2 on a Linux desktop. Would be cool to run on a mainframe!